# How do you play sounds when the python file is in a different directory as the sound file?

Tags: python, audio

So I'm making a text-based game, and after completion, I want to compile the end product to a .exe format so it's fairly easy to share (I plan on using cx_freeze)
Now, I wanted to add some background music for the game, the code below works fine **IF AND ONLY IF** the python file is on the desktop and so is the "sound.wav" I'm looking for ways to execute the sound.wav in background whether it's on the same or different directory as the python file, thanks

```
import winsound
winsound.PlaySound('sound.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

Comment: Perhaps use the absolute path?

Comment: @DeepSpace How so? I'm fairly new to the language

Comment: `'/this/is/absolute/path/to/sound.wav'` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths

Comment: @DeepSpace Doesn't work :( any suggestions?

Comment: What doesn't work? What have you tried?

Comment: What you said, I replaced the "sound.wav" to it's full directory

Answer (score 1):

Use `os` package to generate absolute path to your music file to make sure it always works fine.

For exampe, if your project's structure is

```
root
    src
        your_python_file.py
    assets
        sound.wav
```

So you can generate the absolute path to the sound.wav by

```
import os
# __file__ means the path of the current python script
root_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
bg_path = os.path.join(root_dir, "assets", "sound.wav")
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a sub-folder called `foo` and a second sub-folder called `subfoo`

If you want go into `foo` sub-folder use `foo/sound.wav` if you want to go in the second sub-folder `subfoo` use `foo/subfoo/sound.wav`.

If you want to go up a dictionary you can use `./`.  For example if your sound is located in `foo` and you script in `subfoo` it could be accessed with `./sound.wav` to go up one by one file use `./` again.

Otherwise you can use an 'absolute' file path where you start from `C:` or the drive you wish to access.  For example if your file filename was located in Desktop you could use:

```
C:/users/username/Desktop/foo/subfoo/sound.wav
```